# Hadoop, Java: Context.write() doesn't write anything

Tags: java, hadoop

We're working on a Hadoop project, and our current task is to map lists of foods to feelings according to the times they were eaten. The map phase works, and the reduce phase generates the correct output, but calling Context.write() with that output doesn't write anything to the file.

To check whether the key is valid and 'output' actually has the text that we want it to write, we print the string to System.out, and it is what it's supposed to be. What could cause Context.write() to not write? The "File Output Format Counter" confirms that nothing is being written, because "Bytes Written=8". Those 8 bytes are the file name, I'm guessing.

Here is our Reducer class that won't write. A sample output would be "417004  itchy: shrimp beets nori soy"

```
public static class HourReducer
    extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {
    private Text output = new Text();

    public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Set<String> foods = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> feels = new HashSet<>();

        for(Text item : values) {               
            String[] splitLine = item.toString().split(" ");

            if(splitLine[0].equals("food")) {                   
                foods.add(splitLine[1]);
            }
            else if(splitLine[0].equals("feel")) {                  
                feels.add(splitLine[1]);
            }
        }

        String foodList = "";

        for(String food : foods) {
            foodList += " " + food;
        }

        for(String feel : feels) {
            System.out.println("WRITING at " + key + ": \"" + feel + ":" + foodList + "\"");

            this.output.set(feel + ":" + foodList);
            context.write(key, this.output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well looking at your logic, the only way `context.write()` can run is if `feels`  actually contains anything. If `splitLine[0].equals("feel")` doesnt match anything nothing to will be added to `feels`. I would check your input to the reduce and make sure this is acutally running. Counters are your friend. Add a counter to make sure its running.

Comment: Thanks for your response. `feels` is definitely not empty, because the `println()` statement just before writing to context prints the string that it's supposed to write. Even though the strings that it's supposed to write are correct, i.e. `feels` is not empty, nothing is written.